# Using PayPal API to send money between PayPal Accounts

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to build out a process for users of my app to send money from their PayPal wallet to another user's PayPal wallet.

The idea is that there is no need for credit cards, just wallet to wallet transactions, so that there are no fees attached to the transfer (we're not taking payments or selling goods, just helping people settle their debts with friends and family)

Can anyone confirm whether this is possible with PayPal? And which API / method you would use for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to send money without fees. Such functionality is available in [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) for users from certain countries using certain funding sources (their PayPal balance or a bank)

In general, sending money to another account can be done by adding a `payee` variable to a regular PayPal Checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/

Comment: Great! Simple and effective. Thanks.